# $(window).scroll function will not execute unless I call it manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get jquery to run some code every time that the window is scrolled.  The function works fine if I call it from some other function (for example, calling $(window).scroll from inside another working function, but will not execute natively on a scroll itself. Any ideas what could cause this problem?

For example:

```
$('.someDiv').click(function() {
    $(window).scroll();
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    //do some code
});
```

'some code' only executes when I click on "someDiv" but will not execute on the scrolling of the window.

Comment: Maybe you are scrolling some internal div?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here. There must be something else. Here is a fiddle I started and it works as I would expect it to. http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/kBHfB/

Comment: Your jsfiddle works as expected for me too. There must be some other problem.  I'm going to build a version of your jsfiddle on my server as a test and work from there.

Comment: Solved the problem. The window scroll function called twice every time the window scrolled. This resulted in the code (which toggled the class of a div) running twice, canceling one another out. From the browser, this looked like the code never ran at all.

Answer (score 1):

try binding to body:

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
     //Do Something
})
```

Comment: Didn't work. I was thinking something might be disabling the javascript except it works just fine from the click call.

Comment: Your fiddle crashes my browser.  I think the repeated alert calls without a throttle are what does it. I'm on a low power linux dev machine right now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
 $(window).scroll();
```

});